# Should i use AND while combining mysql query with three IN statements or something else?

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to combine 3 IN statements with ANd in a search im working on.
Here is and example that doesnt fully works as i need it to be

```
SELECT name,thumbnail
 FROM table1 WHERE
       id IN (SELECT imgid FROM categories WHERE category = 22 )
   AND id IN (SELECT imgid FROM namesearch WHERE name LIKE "%car%" )
   OR id IN (SELECT imgid FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE "%jet%" )
```

The above example logically it is in a group like this if im not wrong

```
(categorie=22 AND tags=car) OR (namesearch=jet)
```

And if i search `jet` that is found at `tag` it doesnt filter `category=22`

How can i group the statements in a logic like this

```
(categorie=22) AND (tags=car OR|AND namesearch=jet)
```

It filters category if i put an **AND** like this

```
SELECT name,thumbnail
 FROM table1 WHERE
       id IN (SELECT imgid FROM categories WHERE category = 22 )
   AND id IN (SELECT imgid FROM namesearch WHERE name LIKE "%car%" )
   AND id IN (SELECT imgid FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE "%jet%" )
```

**But will it search in namesearch or tags or at both in the same time?**
Because i dont want to miss tag search if a namesearch is found, i need them both, but namesearch is in high priority.

Comment: You have nothing in your query to bring back anything from the categories, namesearch or tags table. So I am not sure how you mean to give a higher priority to namesearch when the returned row will be identical whichever it matches on. If you want the details you need to use JOINs rather than using IN on a sub query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT name, thumbnail
FROM table1
WHERE id IN (SELECT imgid FROM categories WHERE category = 22 ) AND
      (id IN (SELECT imgid FROM namesearch WHERE name LIKE '%car%' ) OR
       id IN (SELECT imgid FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE '%jet%' )
      )
```

Notice that I used single quotes for the string constants.  This is good practice.

Comment: nicely done gordon, but will it search on both namesearch and tag and will it show both results or only namesearch or tag results?

Comment: @d1t1 . .  It will show rows that match either or both conditions.  Any given row from `table1` will be put in the row set either 0 or 1 times, regardless of the number of matches.